# Some changes to stored procedure don't seem to take effect

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, procedure

Some changes to stored procedures do not seem to be...uhm...acknowledged by Oracle.

For example, I added a parameter to my procedure, recompiled it (in DataGrip-speak), and called it from my code. It seemed to work, it was accepting the new parameter.

However I made a mistake of giving it the type "INT", which does not appear to be a valid type. I tried changing it to "NUMBER", but the behavior is still the same.

Let me explain. I added a primary key to a table (hey, don't judge me, I walked in after the fact, I never would create a table without a primary key), and added it as a parameter to a stored procedure the previous programmer had made that either inserts or updates. However the value they were using as a unique constraint turned out to necessarily be NOT unique anymore, so I added the primary key.

However, every time I'd run the procedure, instead of adding a new row, since one field had the same value, it would update an existing row. It's as if if never recognizes the ID parameter as saying this is a new row. See the code below for clarification.

Luckily for me, a co-worker had run into this problem before and informed me that if I were to copy the procedure definition, rename it, and commit it, and run it, it would work. So I did. And it does.

So, does anyone know why some changes to stored procedures get recognized by Oracle and some changes do not? If this something to do with caching or the way Oracle stores these procedures? Is there a command I can run to "refresh" the storage of procedures since it doesn't automatically seem to do so?

Thanks everyone!

Here's three versions of the procedure: the original, my first change which got recognized, and my second change which did not. Note the v_ID parameter

Original:

```
create PROCEDURE      proc_name_removed_for_privacy
   (  v_Month_Year IN VARCHAR2,
    v_Title IN VARCHAR2,
    v_UserID IN VARCHAR2,
    v_Visible IN CHAR
    )
  as

v_IsNew CHAR(1):= 'T';

BEGIN
     SELECT DECODE(COUNT(Month_Year),0,'T','F') INTO v_IsNew
      FROM table_name_removed_for_privacy
     WHERE Month_Year = v_Month_Year;

      IF UPPER(TRIM(v_IsNew)) = 'T' THEN
        INSERT INTO table_name_removed_for_privacy
        (
            Month_Year,
            Title,
            created_by,
            date_added,
            modified_by,
            date_modified,
            visible
        )
        VALUES(v_Month_Year,v_Title,v_UserID,SYSDATE,v_UserID,SYSDATE,v_Visible);
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        UPDATE table_name_removed_for_privacy
           SET Title = v_Title,
               modified_by = v_UserID,
               date_modified = SYSDATE,
               visible = v_Visible
        WHERE Month_Year = v_Month_Year;
        COMMIT;

    END IF;

END; -- Procedure
```

Second:

```
create PROCEDURE      proc_name_removed_for_privacy
(
    v_Month_Year IN VARCHAR2,
    v_Title IN VARCHAR2,
    v_UserID IN VARCHAR2,
    v_Visible IN CHAR,
    v_ID IN INT DEFAULT -1
) as

BEGIN
    IF v_ID = -1 THEN
        INSERT INTO table_name_removed_for_privacy
        (
            Month_Year,
            Title,
            created_by,
            date_added,
            modified_by,
            date_modified,
            visible
        )
        VALUES(v_Month_Year,v_Title,v_UserID,SYSDATE,v_UserID,SYSDATE,v_Visible);
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        UPDATE table_name_removed_for_privacy
        SET Title = v_Title,
            modified_by = v_UserID,
            date_modified = SYSDATE,
            visible = v_Visible
        WHERE ID = v_ID;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END; -- Procedure
```

Third:

```
create PROCEDURE      proc_name_removed_for_privacy
(
    v_Month_Year IN VARCHAR2,
    v_Title IN VARCHAR2,
    v_UserID IN VARCHAR2,
    v_Visible IN CHAR,
    v_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT -1
) as

BEGIN
    IF v_ID = -1 THEN
        INSERT INTO table_name_removed_for_privacy
        (
            Month_Year,
            Title,
            created_by,
            date_added,
            modified_by,
            date_modified,
            visible
        )
        VALUES(v_Month_Year,v_Title,v_UserID,SYSDATE,v_UserID,SYSDATE,v_Visible);
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        UPDATE table_name_removed_for_privacy
        SET Title = v_Title,
            modified_by = v_UserID,
            date_modified = SYSDATE,
            visible = v_Visible
        WHERE ID = v_ID;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END; -- Procedure
```

Comment: Actually I just realized that, based on the behavior I've described, I'd guess that none of the changes I've made have been recognized by Oracle at all, which is why it's still updated based on the existing v_Month_Year value as seen in the original proc.

WTF.

Comment: `INT` is just subtype of `NUMBER`. [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm)

Comment: *copy the procedure definition, rename it, and commit it* To add a parameter, use ALTER PROCEDURE. That should force a recompile. BTW, I believe DDL statement usually auto commit, so it should not do anything.

Comment: Just FYI: I tried directly running a "create or update procedure" script, and it worked. Well...it updated the proc, but it didn't seem to be liking the NUMBER datatype, so I tried changing it to INTEGER but no amount of "create or update procedure" or recompiling is doing the trick, it still refuses to update.

But...now it looks like my code is working. Oh well. I hate Oracle.

Comment: @MystikDan - What do you mean by "does not like"? Do you mean Oracle is throwing some sort of syntax error in Oracle - or CF. If you mean Oracle errors, you are mostly on your own there ;-)

Comment: @Leigh Actually the behavior was inconsistent. At first, when I would try to update an existing entry, it would instead add it as a new one. But after lunch, it started behaving correctly.

I should note, however, that before I realized it was still working, I tried to run the "create or replace procedure" (I erroneously said "update" above) again to change the datatype from NUMBER to INTEGER (hoping it would fix the problem), the change never took hold, no matter what I did. It's still unchanged today. Did I mention that I hate Oracle?

Comment: Why? Oracle is such fun ;-)  Did you [verify the procs are actually "valid"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:637156098168) like tbone suggested? That one has bitten me a few times...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
create or replace procedure ...
```

My *guess* is that you aren't capturing errors from the create procedure, so you think you are "updating" the procedure with a newer definition, but its really just erroring out.  By using "create or replace" you tell Oracle to create if new else update the existing procedure with the new code.

I don't know this for sure (I'm not running the scripts), but when I see "create procedure" instead of "create or replace", it raises a flag.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15135847)

Comment: @Robert If I'm right, it should solve the problem.  I'll try explaining more when I have more time, thanks

Comment: @tbone It did, but it isn't working everytime. So while luckily my procedure is working now, I'm still inconsistently succeeding at updating or replace procedures in Oracle.

Comment: @MystikDan are you now using "create or replace procedure"?

Comment: @tbone I did. It only seemed to work once. I'm...very confused. I wonder how much of this has to do with DataGrip.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I don't have experience with DataGrip, but it looks like a generic SQL tool.  If you use Oracle's [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) (free btw), do you experience the same issue?